# Adding hyperlink to returned value in QUERY results Google sheets

Tags: google-sheets

I have the following query which is working just fine.
but now I want to take the returned value in A which is a unique number and hyperlink it.

The resulting display should be just the number. The URL for the link is fixed with the number appended at the end e.g.
number = 123456
URL = https:\google.com\123456

my current query is:

```
=iferror(
if(C2="Closed",
QUERY(DATA!A:AA, "
SELECT A,B, D, T, N 
WHERE( AA CONTAINS '" &  lower(C1) & "' AND L =  " & J1 & ") 
Order by T Asc"),
QUERY(DATA!A:AA, "
SELECT A,B, D, R, N 
WHERE( AA CONTAINS '" &  lower(C1) & "' AND L =  " & J1 & ") 
Order by T Asc")
)
```

how can I manipulate the results of the query so each line returned the value in A  is hyperlinked?

Comment: no sorry, I can't share due to the type of data it contains. currently, I'm getting around the problem by adding another column with the following in to create a cell with a hyperlink in it: =iferror(if( B6 <> "", hyperlink(concatenate("https://MYURL.COM/",B6),"Go!"), ""))

Answer (score 0):

**B8: `=QUERY(B2:E5, "select C where E contains 'h11'", 0)`**

**B14: `=ARRAYFORMULA("www.abc.com/"&QUERY(B2:E5, "select C where E contains 'h11'", 0))`**

[image]